# Post 200 OK page is not getting uploaded

Tags: javascript, express

I am running an application in express.
I have a 
Button.which when pushed it wil send a Post to the server.
the 200 Ok, I am having the HTML page.
In Firebug, I can see the HTML payload in 200 OK.

But my page on the Broswer is not getting refreshed/uploaded.

Is it anything that should be done to have the url-refreshed (or) something like that .

I am using this :
    res.sendfile('./temp.html');

The node snip is :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){                                      
res.sendfile('./temp1.html');
});

app.post('/next', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('./temp3.html');                                   
});
```

I am trying to understand why when the 200 OK to post is having the data but it is not shown in the browser. it still have temp1.html

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "But my page on the Browser is not getting refreshed/uploaded"?

Comment: when I open the browser it shows: temp1.html. when I do post (using a button) it is sending POSt and server is calling app.post('next')..and it is responding with 200 OK and temp3.html. I confirmed that in the firebug. but the page in my browser is still temp1.html. looks the page is not getting refreshed

Comment: You want a redirect to be issued, not a 200 ok. Using express it would be this line of code `res.redirect('./temp3.html');` instead of `res.sendfile(...)`

Comment: This fixed my issue partically only I can see 302 redirect . but the issue is : its checking the url as 127.0.0.1/next/temp3.html. it is appending to the url in the browser so it is going to location that is not there ..when I send redirect is there a way I can ask it to send the GET to a particulat url and not appending the exsisting url

Comment: If you read the API docs for Express it tells you exactly how to use it. But besides that I'm not sure I follow you, you DONT want the browser to go to temp3.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a redirect to be issued, not a 200 ok.

Using Express.js it would be this line of code

`res.redirect('./temp3.html');`

instead of

`res.sendfile('./temp3.html)`

For your other question, its trying to access the file that is located at this path: `./temp3.html` , the `./` represents the current directory `../` is parent, which I assume is the one you're after.

As for your third question, if you dont want it to append to the url when redirecting I'm afraid that to my knowledge youre out of luck if you're using "normal post"-behavior.

I think its doable with ajax magic, however someone else has to correct me on that.

[Read the Express res.redirect() docs here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect)

Comment: Thanks @limelights I still see the issue with the re-direct. when the request goes to the server it giving :


Error: invalid json
    at Object.error 
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> 
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:130:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1506:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:374:27)
All I have is GET with the complete url

Comment: Well, thats a completely other problem then! :)

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with JSON. I see thst res.redirect is sending the file  in 200 OK but the issue is the same. Browser is not refershing the page